# Filling the missing values in the specified formate

Tags: python

we can't use numpy or pandas , can anyone help me in finding approach for it
You will be given a string with digits and '_'(missing value) symbols you have to replace the '_' symbols as explained
Ex 1: _, _, _, 24 ==> 24/4, 24/4, 24/4, 24/4 i.e we. have distributed the 24 equally to all 4 places

Ex 2: 40, _, _, _, 60 ==> (60+40)/5,(60+40)/5,(60+40)/5,(60+40)/5,(60+40)/5 ==> 20, 20, 20, 20, 20 i.e. the sum of (60+40) is distributed qually to all 5 places

Ex 3: 80, _, _, _, _  ==> 80/5,80/5,80/5,80/5,80/5 ==> 16, 16, 16, 16, 16 i.e. the 80 is distributed qually to all 5 missing values that are right to it

Ex 4: _, _, 30, _, _, _, 50, _, _
==> we will fill the missing values from left to right
a. first we will distribute the 30 to left two missing values (10, 10, 10, _, _, _, 50, _, _)
b. now distribute the sum (10+50) missing values in between (10, 10, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, _, *)
c. now we will distribute 12 to right side missing values (10, 10, 12, 12, 12, 12, 4, 4, 4)
for a given string with comma seprate values, which will have both missing values numbers like ex: "*, _, x, _, _, *" you need fill the missing values
Q: your program reads a string like ex: "*, _, x, _, _, _" and returns the filled sequence

Comment: Could you post what you have done so far ?

Answer (score 0):

Tried to cover as many edge cases as possible:

```
inp = "80, _, _, _, _"
inp=inp.split(", ")
start=-1
end=-1
new_arr=inp.copy()
for i in range(len(inp)):
    if (inp[i]=='_')&(i!=len(inp)-1):
        continue
    elif start==-1:
        if i==0:  ## 0th position element has non blank value
            # print("cond1")
            start=0
            end=0
            new_arr[i]=int(inp[i])
        else:
            # print("cond2")
            start=i
            end=i
            avg=int(inp[start])/(i+1)
            for k in range(0, start+1):
                new_arr[k]=avg
    elif i==len(inp)-1:  ## reached last element
        # print("cond3")
        avg=int(new_arr[start])/(i+1-start)
        for k in range(start, i+1):
            new_arr[k]=avg
    else:
        # print("cond4")
        end=i
        if end-start>1:  ## blank are present
            avg=(int(new_arr[start])+int(new_arr[end]))/(end-start+1)
            for k in range(start, end+1):
                new_arr[k]=avg
        start=end
    print(new_arr)
```

The complexity of this is ~ O(n), space complexity ~ O(n)

Answer (score 0):

Based only on what you've given,
This is a **dumb** implementation of what is being asked for.

```
def fill_in(s : str):
    l = s.split(',')
    last = -1
    for e, i in enumerate(l):
        if i.strip() != '_':
            if last==-1:
                filler = float(i) / (e+1)
                l = [filler]*(e+1) + l[e+1:]
                last = e
            else:
                filler = (l[last] + float(i)) / (e - last +1)
                l = l[0:last] + [filler]*(e - last +1) + l[e+1:]
                last = e
        
        elif e==len(l)-1:
            if last==-1:
                last = 0
            filler = l[last] / (len(l) - last)
            l = l[:last] + [filler]*(len(l) - last)
        
    return l
```

Usage:

```
fill_in('_, _, 30, _, _, _, 50, _, _')
```

Returns:

```
[10.0, 10.0, 12.0, 12.0, 12.0, 12.0, 4.0, 4.0, 4.0]
```